# Which table or columns store the changes made to a Hybris Type?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Does anyone have an idea which table or columns store the changes made to a
`hybris` Type?

suppose I changed the value of 'name' attribute for `Client` type in `hmc`, hybris logs this as a change (under changes field) and I can see it in HMC. However if I want to seee it in the database where I can see this? Please suggest.

Comment: One can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52063564/2478134)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

savedvalues, savedvalueentry, props

A SavedValue object contains one or more SavedValueEntries which contains the old and new value (props)