# Finding out the place where an attribute of a model changes in Hybris

Tags: java, cron, jobs, sap-commerce-cloud

I have a custom attribute called ***visibility*** in ***CategoryModel*** and it can be changed both from backoffice manually and from a cronjob which checks whether there is at least one product under the category. If it is changed from backoffice, cronjob should not change the visibility  even if any product is found under it. When an attribute is changed from backoffice, section called ***Last Changes*** in ***Backoffice*** registers changes related to attribute but I could not find how or where it is done.

How can I find out the place where an attribute of a model changes? ***From Backoffice or Cronjob or something like that?***

Comment: As a suggestion, In the cronjob, you can log the moddifications performed on the attribute. By doing that you can track how the cronjob is modifying that value

Answer (score 3):

SavedValues - Keeping Track of Attribute Value Modification

If you modify the value of an attribute in Backoffice then the original value of the attribute (before modification) and the new value (after modification) stores in SavedValues. Early v6.7 there was HMC API to deal with SavedValues, but now you have to write the flexible query to get the entries from the service layer.

Find more [detail here](https://help.hybris.com/1808/hcd/8c535eff86691014b7dccb3539092813.html)

---

### Edit: Answer to your question

> How can I find out the place where an attribute of a model changes?
>   From Backoffice or Cronjob or something like that?

Find the attribute entry into the SavedValueEntry, if the current attribute value matches the `newValue`, then it was modified from the backoffice otherwise from the cronjob.

[image]

---

Other references
[savedvalues-in-hybris](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/17620/savedvalues-in-hybris.html)
[how-to-access-savedvalues-and-savedvalue-entries](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/18014/how-to-access-savedvalues-and-savedvalue-entries-f.html)

Comment: I think, that only modifications in backoffice are stored as saved values, right? So when a cronjob modifies an item, there is no saved value.

Comment: yes @JohannesNolte, as I mentioned it only stores history for backoffice/hmc modification. So for cronJob, one has to write custom service to save history. Unfortunately, OOTB service API is not available.